# I need help planning my bike renovation!

Tags: fork, handlebars, rims

I'm planning on buying this bike online and making it, well y'know, mine. And to do this, I would like to make it look like an Aristotle bike. So I'm basically am going to need new rims to start and a bunch of other stuff.

The main problem I've confronted is the bike fork. I want to change it but I don't know where to start in choosing one. Plus I would like to change the handlebars but I can't figure out the name of the style.
[image]

^^^ Here's the bike I plan on renovating... ^^^

[image]

^^^ ...and here's an idea of what I'd like it to look like at the end of its "makeover"... ^^^

Comment: If you're planning on using new parts, and replace the wheels, tires, bars, and seat, which is probably about the minimum you could get away with while making it look somewhat similar to the result bike, you would have spent at least $200. If you want to replace the crankset, pedals, and forks, you are probably getting close to what it would just cost to buy the bike new.  I don't have much experience with swapping forks, but if you put a straight blade fork in, the bike geometry would change quite a bit as the rest of the frame wasn't designed for it and the tire might rub on the downtube.

Comment: That an older style headset.  You will have trouble finding modern forks for the bike.  It is better to buy a modern bike than it is to modernize an old bike.

Comment: What is the bike you are buying?  Is it a new bike with retro look or a true old bike?

Comment: @BPugh Really you think OP is going to buy a brand new retro and then convert it?

Comment: @blam, I'm hoping that is the case, hate to see it carved up loosing some history.  Other hand though, it may be a cheap new bike.  Either way if we knew what it was, then we can get a better idea what needs changed.

Answer (score 5):

By the time you get the bike looking similar to the latter, you'd be better off buying the latter. The fork controls part of the geometry and changing the fork will make it different. Also, you need access to tools for replacing the fork (lets leave aside the different types of headsets for now, since that is part of the aesthetic). Then, you need to buy a flat bar instead of the swept back bars you have now. This is trivial to replace. You can use the existing brake levers, but if you want to match style, you can buy some new modern levers for pretty cheap. A new saddle isn't too expensive, i suppose either. The new wheels alone will probably run you over 200 dollars anyway since they're hipster-y.

It looks like these Aristotle bicycles retail for around 400 dollars. Given that a new fork is probably going to run at least 50-60 dollars, a new wheelset 200 dollars, a new riser bar 20 dollars, saddle probably 30-40 bucks, you're going to run probably more than the new bike costs. Thats also excluding the time + tools you may need to buy/borrow + paint and the bicycle you want to "restore" (plus, some hipster would likely find that bike attractive as it is).

And given that that bike looks like its not in America, note that these fixed/single speed bikes with flip flop hubs which look like the Aristotle bike are pretty damn common now among the hipsters - it shouldn't be hard to find a new one under the price of doing this conversion in Europe.